# Streaming pydub output from azure to local machine

Tags: python-3.x, azure, audio, pydub

I am using `pydub` to play a `wav` file. It all works fine locally. But I want to run it on my azure machine. How can stream the audio to my local machine and listen it on my earphones? All I see is this output with increasing time - as if it's streaming the audio somewhere.

`python3 play-audio.py`

```
Input #0, wav, from '/tmp/tmp0cvn0bz4.wav':   0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
  Duration: 00:00:05.96, bitrate: 128 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 8000 Hz, 1 channels, s16, 128 kb/s
   6.00 M-A:  0.000 fd=   0 aq=    0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0
```

Answer (score 1):

Better run the script locally and let it access the file on your remote server.

See [Azure Python SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python) and [pydub issue with accessing a remote file](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/issues/56)

Comment: I thought that too. But there are many other related things that I think will be messed up. I am looking for an easier solution.